# Loading large files GWT client side

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT.

I want to load a large text file (50 MB) from GWT client side and output the file content in a textarea.

I tried Requestbuilder and I passed response.getText() to a string. I am able to do this for a 10-12 MB file but then it just hangs. I think it has something to do with some maximum limit of string. I can not pass the output of response.getText() to a file because then I would not be able to read that file from GWT client side as I'd need bufferreader and all.

I don't know how to make server chunk the file and send one by one responses.

Can anybody please help me with it!

Comment: Please mention you server environment. Is is Tomcat or Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Although the best option will be a server servlet to split the file so as the client could show it paginated, another option is to make the browser natively deal with the big data.

Create an iframe whose source is the url of the file in the server. If the server sends the correct headers (text/plain) the browser will show the content correctly.

```
 Frame f = new Frame("path_to_myfile.txt");
 f.setSize("600px", "400px");
 RootPanel.get().add(f);
```